# angular gm-places-autocomplete TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: json, angularjs, autocomplete, maps, angular-ngmodel

*hello, I recovered in a map an input angular autocomplete .
But I have this back*

**Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{ formData }}
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON**

```js
(function(window, document) {

// Create all modules and define dependencies to make sure they exist
// and are loaded in the correct order to satisfy dependency injection
// before all nested files are concatenated by Grunt

// Config
angular.module('gm.config', [])
    .value('gm.config', {
        debug: true,
        placess: {
            autocomplete: {}
        }
    })
    .run(['$window', function($window){

        // Check for dependencies
        if(
            angular.isUndefined($window.google) ||
            angular.isUndefined($window.google.maps)
            ){
            throw new Error('Google Maps API not available, please make sure the Google Maps library is loaded before the AngularJS Google Maps library is loaded');
        }
    }]);

// Places modules
angular.module('gm.places.directives', []);
angular.module('gm.places', [
    'gm.places.directives'
])
    .run(['$window', function($window){

        // Check for dependencies
        if(
            angular.isUndefined($window.google) ||
            angular.isUndefined($window.google.maps) ||
            angular.isUndefined($window.google.maps.places) ||
            angular.isUndefined($window.google.maps.places.Autocomplete)
            ){
            throw new Error('Google Maps API not available, please make sure the Google Maps library is loaded before the AngularJS Google Maps library is loaded');
        }
    }]);

// Modules
angular.module('gm.directives', []);
angular.module('gm.filters', []);
angular.module('gm.services', []);
angular.module('gm', [
    'gm.config',
    'gm.directives',
    'gm.filters',
    'gm.services',
    'gm.places'
]);
/**
 * Logger service
 */
angular.module('gm.services')
    .factory('logger', ['$log', '$window', function ($log, $window) {

        // Create service
        var service = {};

        // Proxy regular methods to $log
        angular.forEach(['log', 'info', 'warn', 'error'], function(method){
            service[method] = function(){
                return $log[method](arguments);
            };
        });


        // Add dir method to hierarchically display objects
        service.dir = function (obj, title) {
            if ($window.console) {
                if (angular.isDefined(title)) {
                    $log.info(title + ':');
                }
                $window.console.dir(obj);
            }
        };

        return service;
    }]);angular.module('gm.places')
    .directive('gmPlacesAutocomplete', ['$rootScope', 'gm.config', 'logger', function($rootScope, gmConfig, logger){

        var configOptions = (gmConfig.places && gmConfig.places.autocomplete) || {};

        return {
            restrict: 'AEC',
            require : ['gmPlacesAutocomplete', '?ngModel'],
            controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$transclude', function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude){

                this._options = angular.extend({}, configOptions, $scope.$eval($attrs.gmOptions));
                this._element = $element[0];
                this._api = undefined;

                // Define properties
                Object.defineProperties(this, {
                    element: {
                        get: function(){
                            return this._element;
                        },
                        configurable: false
                    },
                    api: {
                        get: function(){
                            return this._api;
                        },
                        configurable: false
                    }
                });

                try {
                    this._api = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this._element, this._options);
                }
                catch (err)
                {
                    if(gmConfig.debug) logger.log('Could not instantiate gmPlacesAutocomplete directive: ' + err.message);
                }

            }],
            link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controllers){

                // Define controllers
                var gmPlacesAutocompleteController = controllers[0];
                var ngModelController = controllers[1];

                // Set initial model value if a model is defined
                if (ngModelController) {
                    ngModelController.$setViewValue(gmPlacesAutocompleteController.api);
                }

                // Listen to place_changed event
                google.maps.event.addListener(gmPlacesAutocompleteController.api, 'place_changed',
                    (function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, gmPlacesAutocompleteController, ngModelController, $rootScope){
                        return function(){

                            // Update model if there is one
                            if (ngModelController) {
                                ngModelController.$setViewValue(gmPlacesAutocompleteController.api);
                            }

                            // Broadcast event
                            $rootScope.$broadcast('gmPlacesAutocomplete::placeChanged', gmPlacesAutocompleteController);
                        };
                    })(scope, iElement, iAttrs, gmPlacesAutocompleteController, ngModelController, $rootScope)
                );

            }
        };

    }]);})(window, document);

.controller('controller', function($scope) {
    
    // we will store all of our form data in this object
    $scope.formData = {};
    
});
```

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="formData.place" gm-places-autocomplete />
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the Circular Structure of the `formData` Object, I hope you need to print the `formData` in your page using angular expression, I'm facing the same issue but i don't have the best solution but we can use the following code to print that variable in the console using $watch like the following.

```
        $scope.$watch('myForm.myModel', function(newValue,oldValue){
            console.log('watch...');
            console.log($scope.formData);
        });
```